# Create Windows app similar to Windows 7 Gadgets

Tags: windows

I'm looking for an idea of how to develop a simple Windows application which will show an image (overlayed and always on top). An image should be clickable. 
Similar to gadgets in Windows 7. 
How to do it? Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

To make the window overlay, use [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes)
and to make it top most set the **WS_EX_TOPMOST** extended style at creation

Comment: Thank you. I will talk with my programmer in the next days about it.